# 'Retina' resolution on a 5k Dell monitor

Tags: mac, hdmi, external-display, displayport, thunderbolt

Oh my God. It feels like even having long conversations with both Apple and Dell that I cannot get an answer to my question so let me try and figure this out.

I have a 15" Macbook Pro Retina mid-2014. It has an HDMI port and 2 Thunderbolt2 ports. I'm going to be buying the Dell UP2715k 5k monitor. It's video ports are as follows (http://icdn5.digitaltrends.com/image/dell-up2715k-monitor-jacks-1500x1000.jpg): 1 Mini Display Port, 2 Display Ports.

I am wanting to connect them both together so on the 5k monitor it would downsample to show my retina resolution. I hope that makes sense.

I chatted with Dell and they suggested a Thunderbolt (or Mini Display Port) to Display Port which would allow for both audio/video and display as retina on the 5k. They also said I could use HDMI to Display Port too.

Apple had no clue. Typical.

What are people's thoughts? I know you can do it with one cable now (based on reading!) but I have no idea if Apple/Dell are correct?

Also. I know 'retina' is just a marketing term but thought I may as well use it as it's driving me insane.

Thanks!

**UPDATE 30/11/16**

I bought the Dell UP2715k 5k monitor and connecting it to my MBP via two miniDP to DP cables. All generally works okay but I get this odd split screen thing which stops the cursor from being as responsive and accurate. Any thoughts? Videos below of issue.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVMV4RwYZeI
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEObJB94eTI
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FlD2GA9Gv8w

Comment: The ability to set the resolution on the Macbook will be determined by its GPU.  It appears based on the outputs, you have to use 2 DP for 5k3k or 1 mDP for 4k2k.

Comment: 15" Retina should be 2880x1800 so that would be mDP. You could always go for the 2 DP solution.

Comment: Thanks, folks. How would I plug 2 DPs into my MBPr? Use the two Thunderbolt ports?

Comment: Also, okay the resolution of the MBPr is 2880x1800 but the 5k monitor is 27"... wouldn't it need resolution?

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit your question confused me a little. Below is some info that may help you out.

The 15" Macbook Pro (Retina mid-2014) model will support a single-stream 4K (3840 x 2160) display at 60Hz so long as you are running OS X Yosemite v10.10.3 or later. **What version of macOS are you running?**

Officially, when using external displays, your Mac displays up to 2560 x 1600 pixels (when using Thunderbolt) or up to 3840 x 2160 pixels at 30Hz or 4096 x 2160 pixels at 24Hz (when using HDMI).

It can also run up to two 4K displays at 60Hz with the NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M graphics card.

This model Mac, however, could ship with either an Intel Iris Pro 5200 (2.2 GHz) or NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M and Intel Iris Pro 5200 (2.5 and 2.8 GHz) graphics card. **Which graphics card have you got?**

The Dell UP2715k 5k 27" you reference is an LED-lit IPS 5K display with 5120 × 2880 resolution at up to 60Hz. Two DisplayPort-to-DisplayPort and two DisplayPort-to-Mini DisplayPort and 1 Mini DisplayPort-to-Mini DisplayPort cables are in the box (see the [Quick Start Guide](http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_display_projector/esuprt_display/dell-up2715k-monitor_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf)). This display supports multi-stream transport (MST) in both landscape and portrait viewing modes, and yes your Mac also supports MST at 60 Hz.

You may want to refer to the following:

- [Issues Apple Mac platform users may encounter using the UP2715k Dell UltraSharp 27 Ultra HD 5K Monitor](http://www.dell.com/Support/Article/au/en/audhs1/SLN295121)
- [Dell UP2715k User's Guide](http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_display_projector/esuprt_display/dell-up2715k-monitor_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply.

I am running macOS Sierra.
I have the NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB graphics card on my MBPr.

What cable would I need to connect to the 5k to have at least my MBPr resolution matched?

Comment: I have connected my MBPr using two miniDP to DP and everything is generally fine but half the screen (right hand side) is pixelated!

Comment: What version of macOS are you running? Have you tried outputting different resolutions? Also, your monitor has a built-in diagnostic tool (see the USer's Guide), have you tried that to determine the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need a 2015 (or later) Macbook 15" with discrete GPU to run that monitor. With your laptop that monitor will not work.

Comment: Could you add some technical details on why it would or wouldn't work? It seems like that the other answer has all that information? Why not up vote it instead?

Answer (score 0):

Turning off spaces per monitor fixes the cursor problem as demo'd in the youtube links on my setup.

Do this by going into System Preferences, Mission Control, the unticking 'Displays Have Seperate Spaces'

See -
http://www.mactrast.com/2013/10/disable-second-menu-bar-os-x-mavericks/

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.